# Xamarin Prism Unable to Navigate to New Page

Tags: c#, xamarin

When I try to open the following page it just freezes. I've deleted everything from the page but it still happens!!!!!!! I have no idea whats going on.

View Mode

```
public class selectedIngredientViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    
    INavigationService _navigationService;

  

    public selectedIngredientViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {



        _navigationService = navigationService;

        
    }



}
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="RecipeDatabaseXamarin.Views.ingredientListPage"
          NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

<StackLayout Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    
    <Label x:Name="lblIngredientName" Text="Name:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" Margin="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Left"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Call to this page

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("selectedIngredientPage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you just need to `await` this

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("selectedIngredientPage");
```

If you are coming from another thread, you may need to marshal back to the main thread (only if you are on another thread)

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("selectedIngredientPage");
});
```

Also you need to make sure you have registered correctly

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SelectedIngredientPage>();
}
```

---

**Further Reading**

- [Navigation Basics](http://%20https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html)

Comment: Appreciate it. I was using another's class clAsyncHelpers which allows you to run a async as sync but somethign must be messed as as the await worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently. I can't wait for Xamarin to be as easy as it is to code for C# as a windows form app.